# keep table headers still when scrolling a table?

Tags: html

I have the following table which inside a model dialog and I have applied some css to, so that the head stays in the same position when its being scrolled.

however after I load the page the columns are pushed to the left, these 5 columns should appear under the headers.

also the underlying page has been pushed to the left of the page also.

```
               <style>
                    .tblSearchMedia1 tbody {
                    height: 100px;
                    overflow: auto;
                        }
                    .tblSearchMedia1 td {
                    padding: 3px 10px;
                    }

                    .tblSearchMedia1 thead > tr, tbody{
                    display:block;

                    }
                </style>


                <table class="tblSearchMedia1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th> Region </th>
                        <th> Subregion </th>
                        <th> Country </th>
                        <th> Media Type </th>
                        <th> Media Name </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: MediaGroups">
                    <tr>
                        <td data-bind="text: ID"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: ID"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text:ID"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: ID"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: ID"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

[image]

[Link to Larger image](http://postimg.org/image/av71kh86b/full/)

Comment: Does this fiddle show the problem you're having? http://jsfiddle.net/wuwdY/1/

Comment: no, I have added a link to the original image

Comment: Got it!  I'm fairly certain the problem is your `display:block;` I bet if you remove that, it'll line up, but I also believe that will remove the scrolling.  I'll keep thinking on it.

Comment: Take a look here: http://tjvantoll.com/2012/11/10/creating-cross-browser-scrollable-tbody/ – this might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if this solves your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/javitube/DLjLn/1/

```
    .tblSearchMedia1
    {
        width:500px;
    }
    .tblSearchMedia1 tbody {
        height: 50px;
        overflow:auto;
        display:block;
        width:100%;
    }

    .tblSearchMedia1 thead th, .tblSearchMedia1 tbody td
    {
        width: 100px;
    }
    .tblSearchMedia1 td {
        padding: 3px 10px;
    }
    .tblSearchMedia1 thead > tr {
        position:relative;
        display:block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I changed your CSS and just used generic selectors for ease of making an example.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
th, td {
    border:1px solid black;
}
.tblSearchMedia1 thead {
    position: absolute;
    width: 525px;
}
.tblSearchMedia1 tbody {
    width: 525px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.tblSearchMedia1 th {
    background: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.tblSearchMedia1 tbody {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50px;
}
.tblSearchMedia1 th, td {
    width: 75px;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I assigned set widths and set the thead position to fixed.

Here is the working fiddle.

Updated fiddle to prevent header from floating when parent DOM scrolls.

http://jsfiddle.net/wuwdY/7/

Comment: the headings stay in one place on the screen and move out of the jquery dialog if i scroll the main window.

Comment: @xerxes Fixed, see new fiddle.  Used `absolute` instead of `fixed` and `blocked`.

Comment: I have found another problem, http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/7444/81q.png
if a column has a string which is longer than the td with it pushes them out of the headings bounderies, can you fix this, if yes then I will choose yours as the correct answer.

Comment: @Xerxes Off hand it looks like possible padding issue.  I'll see if I can duplicate it in my fiddle.  Here is a new fiddle with some longer text in places.  Can you repeat the problem in this fiddle?  I'm guessing some where in your code the CSS I'm using isn't the same or being overridden. http://jsfiddle.net/wuwdY/8/

Comment: @xerxes make sure you have this line in your CSS `.tblSearchMedia1 th, td { width: 75px;padding: 3px 10px;}` it's what's keeping the cells all the same width and along word wrapping inside.

Comment: I dont want to set an absolute width as the values that come into the tds will be of different lengths, they should therefor change their size to accomodate for the difference and wrap large texts, and this shouldnt make them fall out of the table header alignments.